# How to design auto layout constraint for all iPhone devices using only one storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, size-classes

**Image Description** :

[image]

I want to fit these labels size and horizontal margins both 4" and 4.7" devices.

I set labels width and set auto shrink: minimum font scale, but it doesn't work.

How to separate two "Title" labels?

Comment: Do you want two rows? Or just want shrink effect.

Comment: zcui93/ Just want shrink effect

Comment: As you said you set the labels width, can you confirm that the size of the label is shrunk, but not the text font?

Comment: Zcui93/ To solve these issue, I can change anything to need.

Comment: For small screens, it's better to split it into two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

> UIStackView

for the required UI.
Here are the setup steps

[image]

[image]